# How to print out value on controller Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, printing, console, console.log

I'm beginner on Laravel...

How to debug some value on controller in Laravel, result can show to console like syntax `console.log()` on javascript?

example controller function :

```
class TestMeController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jsonify');
    }

    public function callMe($id)
    {
        $params = Request::all();

        console.log($id);  <== how to write code on Laravel?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Laravel use **`dd($id)`** or if you don't want to halt the execution, you can use **`dump($var)`**.
You can still always use PHP's native functions like ***`var_dump`***, ***`die`*** and ***`print_r`***.

Answer (score 10):

You can Use these several methods for printing in **Laravel**.

```
1. dump($var)
2. dd($id)
3. var_dump($var)
4. die($var)
5. print_r($var)
```

Answer (score 4):

`dd($var)` is great because it stops the program after it runs so by moving it around you get a good sense of which line of code is causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using laravel 7 with blade templates and to test my controller
**(MVC ARCHITECHTURE)**
I usually use:

```
return dd($variable)
```

or even just

```
return $variable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the data

```
$events = new Event();
    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($events->all()->toArray()); 
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a return response with json:

```
return response()->json($dataVar, status_code);
```

instead console.log();

```
return response()->json($id, 200);
```